# Angular doesn't work for safari browser

Tags: angular, safari

Now I want to run my angular2 page on safari browser.

But it doesn't work correctly. (It works well on chrome).

So I have tried to search resolution on StackOverflow, it says about polyfill, core-js, es6-shim.

But I don't know how to use them.

I have included shim.min.js  in index.html according to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

But the browser console shows as below.

> GET http://localhost/frontend/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js 404 (Not Found)

And I have tried importing 'intl' in file polyfills.ts.
But the result is same.

This is my error log

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://10.70.1.6/frontend/D:/Work/Project/FrontEnd/src/polyfills.js.map

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://10.70.1.6/frontend/Observable.js.map

[Error] ERROR – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'me.selected_group[0]') — main.bundle.js:3177
    error
    View_AdminSchedulesEditexistingComponent_3
    logError (vendor.bundle.js:17953)
    (anonymous function)
    handleError (vendor.bundle.js:5973)
    tick (vendor.bundle.js:9889)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:9762:111)
    invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:10900)
    onInvoke (vendor.bundle.js:8957)
    invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:10899)
    run (polyfills.bundle.js:10660)
    run (vendor.bundle.js:8825)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:9762:86)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:8659)
    __tryOrUnsub (vendor.bundle.js:19278)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:19225)
    _next (vendor.bundle.js:19165)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:19129)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:19491)
    emit (vendor.bundle.js:8645)
    checkStable (vendor.bundle.js:8922)
    onLeave (vendor.bundle.js:8998)
    onInvokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:8951)
    invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:10932)
    runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:10700)
    invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:10995)
[Error] ERROR CONTEXT – DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 3, nodeDef: Object, …}
    error
    View_AdminSchedulesEditexistingComponent_3
    logError (vendor.bundle.js:17953)
    (anonymous function)
    handleError (vendor.bundle.js:5978)
    tick (vendor.bundle.js:9889)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:9762:111)
    invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:10900)
    onInvoke (vendor.bundle.js:8957)
    invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:10899)
    run (polyfills.bundle.js:10660)
    run (vendor.bundle.js:8825)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:9762:86)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:8659)
    __tryOrUnsub (vendor.bundle.js:19278)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:19225)
    _next (vendor.bundle.js:19165)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:19129)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:19491)
    emit (vendor.bundle.js:8645)
    checkStable (vendor.bundle.js:8922)
    onLeave (vendor.bundle.js:8998)
    onInvokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:8951)
    invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:10932)
    runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:10700)
    invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:10995)
```

How can I resolve this? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CLI then have a look at the polyfills.ts file. Uncomment the imports and install the packages mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using angular cli and I know polyfill.ts is there. But I don't know which feature is imported for safari.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago and for Safari I was just missing the imports for intl import 'intl' and import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en'

Comment: I have tried import 'intl'; in file polyfills.ts. But result is same.

Comment: Hmmm... have you installed intl? npm install --save intl

Comment: Ludwig, I solved problem without intl. It is not intl problem. So I think whether polyfills is really necessary thing for Safari support. I use Angular 4. Perhaps Angular 4 support Safari basically, right?

Comment: Alex how you resolve your problem as I am also facing same issue with safari.

Comment: @AbelJojo , I use Angular 4, and it works well without any changing polyfills. I think Angular 4 supports Safari well.

Comment: i too use angular 4 but safari 8 gives map file not found issue on ipad